# jQuery hover - How to make div appear on hover, then remain visible

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a dropdown login box which is displayed when the user hovers the cursor over the 'login-trigger', which is just an image. Once the dropdown appears, I want to be able to hover over the "login-box" element (the dropdown) without it disappearing, which is what is happening right now. Is there any way to make it remain in view when hovering over both the trigger and the dropdown itself, and only vanish when the cursor is not hovering on either of these elements?

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#login-trigger").hover(function() {
            $("#login-box").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to nest the elements in a common container, and attach the mouse events to that container :

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="login-trigger" src="image.png" />
    <div id="login-box">
         <!-- login stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and just use css:

```
#container #login-box {display:none;}
#container:hover #login-box {display:block;}
```

or javascript

```
$('#container').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $('#login-box')[e.type=='mouseenter'?'slideDown':'slideUp']('slow');
});
```

If that's not possible, you have to use a timeout and event handlers on both the trigger and the box, which is a quite a bit more complicated.

```
$('#login-trigger, #login-box').on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'login-trigger') $('#login-box').slideDown('slow');
        clearTimeout( $('#login-box').data('timer') );
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('#login-box').data('timer', 
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#login-box').slideUp('slow')
            }, 300)
        );
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xjLVE/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `#login-box` in `#login-trigger`.

Then when you will be hover `#login-box`, you will also be hover `#login-trigger`

Comment: $("#login-trigger", "#login-box").hover(function() --- like this?

Comment: No, in your html, like this: <div id="login-trigger"><div id="login-box"></div></div>